# NSComboBoxCell won't display values

Tags: nstableview, nstableviewcell

So I have a perfect working NSTableView for a Mac App. I added a new column on it, and I am trying to set it as Combo, but I am facing a lot of issues.
First is, if I drag and drop the NSComboBoxCell on the Storyboard, it will lose all my other columns (weird thing #1). So I decided to overwrite my NSTextFieldCell, which looks like is the way to go. But now the items on my combobox are not showing up.

```
- (NSView*)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
 NSTableCellView *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];    

if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"typeCell"]) {
    NSComboBoxCell *combo =(NSComboBoxCell*) [cell.textField viewWithTag:10];

    [combo addItemsWithObjectValues:@[@"Test"]];

}
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?
The column is also already editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing `NSTableCellView` (a subclass of `NSView`, used for cells in a view based table view) and `NSTextFieldCell` (a subclass of `NSCell`, used for cells in a cell based table view).

Solution to weird thing 1: drag a `NSComboBox` (without `Cell`) to the table view.

`viewForTableColumn` should return a (subclass of) `NSView`, not a (subclass of) `NSCell`.

`[cell.textField viewWithTag:10]` returns a subview of a `NSTextField`. You shouldn't put subviews in `NSTextField`s and I don't think you did.

> the items on my combobox are not showing up

`combo` is `nil`.

Comment: tks! The solution for Weird Thing 1 actually solved the problem!